# Is there a difference between "+" and "{1,}" in regex?

Tags: regex

I was learning about regex and found out that `+` and the `{1,}` have the same function. What I was wondering is whether there is any difference between the two?

I tried finding out the execution times by copying a standard passage and executing the regex patterns using the above two operators. I found out that the execution time for `{1,}` was faster than that of `+`. Can anyone explain why?

```
pattern1 = r'/[A-Z]{1,}/g'
pattern2 = r'/[A-Z]+/g'
```

Comment: `{1,}` = `+` unless it is BRE POSIX

Comment: Yes, they're equivalent. If the performance is different, it's a flaw in the RE engine.

Comment: How much faster was it?

Comment: thanks for the clarification :) {1,} took 4ms whereas + took 6ms

Comment: @T.Square it seems like you are using Python. If so, I just ran `%timeit` from ipython and the mean time taken are `183 us` and `184 us`. If you're testing for time, make sure you're checking over multiple runs and using some timing mechanism that doesn't also time garbage collection, etc.

Comment: @Chrispresso, I was just about to try taking the mean time. Thanks though :)